# Microsoft Graph Explorer checkout returns status code 500 "Unknown error"

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I would like to checkout a file and I am issuing the following POST request in Microsoft Graph Explorer: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/<drive-id>/items/<item-id>/checkout`

I get the following error code:

> Failure - Status Code 500

and the following response:

```
"error": {
    "code": "-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UnknownError",
    "message": "Unknown Error",
}
```

I tried to checkin the file with the following POST request `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/<drive-id>/items/<item-id>/checkin` and then I get the error:

```
"error": {
    "code": "invalidRequest",
    "message": "The file is not checked out."
}
```

What do I need to do to checkout the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`/checkin`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-checkin) and [`/checkout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-checkout) endpoints are only available in the Beta version:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/drives/{driveId}/items/{itemId}/checkout
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/drives/{driveId}/items/{itemId}/checkin
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize that. It's confusing that I can use a URL with `/v1.0` but still reach a `/beta` endpoint. It's also confusing that `checkin` seems to work (it gives sensible output) but `checkout` only returns `Unknown error`.